# How to switch out of root acount during server set up?

Tags: ansible

I need to automate the deployment of some remote Debian servers. These servers come with only the root account. I wish to make it such that the only time I ever need to login as root is during the set up process. Subsequent logins will be done using a regular user account, which will be created during the set up process.

However during the set up process, I need to set `PermitRootLogin no` and `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Then I will be doing a `service sshd restart`. This will stop the ssh connection because ansible had logged into the server using the root account.

My question is: How do I make ansible ssh into the root account, create a regular user account, set `PermitRootLogin no` and `PasswordAuthentication no`, then ssh into the server using the regular user account and do the remaining set up tasks?

It is entirely possible that my set-up process is flawed. I will appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually manage the entire setup process with Ansible, without requiring manual configuration prerequisites.

Interestingly, you can change `ansible_user` and `ansible_password` on the fly, using `set_fact`.  Remaining tasks executed after `set_fact` will be executed using the new credentials:

```
- name: "Switch remote user on the fly"
  hosts: my_new_hosts
  vars:
    reg_ansible_user: "regular_user"
    reg_ansible_password: "secret_pw"
  gather_facts: false
  become: false
  tasks:

  - name: "(before) check login user"
    command: whoami
    register: result_before

  - debug: msg="(before) whoami={{ result_before.stdout }}"

  - name: "change ansible_user and ansible_password"
    set_fact:
      ansible_user: "{{ reg_ansible_user }}"
      ansible_password: "{{ reg_ansible_password }}"

  - name: "(after) check login user"
    command: whoami
    register: result_after

  - debug: msg="(after) whoami={{ result_after.stdout }}"
```

Furthermore, you don't have to fully restart `sshd` to cause configuration changes to take effect, and existing SSH connections will stay open.  Per `sshd(8)` manpage:
`sshd rereads its configuration file when it receives a hangup signal, SIGHUP...`.

So, your setup playbook could be something like:

1. login initially with the root account
2. create the regular user and set his password or configure `authorized_keys`
3. configure sudoers to allow regular user to execute commands as root
4. use `set_fact` to switch to that account for the rest of the playbook (remember to use `become: true` on tasks after this one, since you have switched from root to regular user.  you might even try executing a test sudo command before locking root out)
5. change sshd configuration
6. execute `kill -HUP`*`<sshd_pid>`*
7. verify by setting `ansible_user` back to root, fail if login works

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to make a standard user account and add it to sudoers. You could then run ansible with the standard user and if you need a command to run as `root`, you just prefix with command with `sudo`.

I wrote an article about setting up a deploy user
http://www.altmake.com/2013/03/06/secure-lamp-setup-on-amazon-linux-ami/